# Lenovo Yoga 3 10' sd card?

Tags: lenovo

HAPPY HOLIDAYS!

So basically i'm trying to find any info what SD cards does Lenovo yoga 3 supports.
Would it support [SAMSUNG 32GB MICRO SDHC EVO PLUS CLASS 10](http://www.1a.lv/datortehnika_preces_birojam/datu_neseji/atminas_kartes/samsung_32gb_micro_sdhc_evo_plus_class_10_sd_adapter)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lenovo Yoga 3 10" MicroSD card slot supports every MicroSD card upto 128GB, so this Samsung what you have mentioned will be a good choice.